# Não consigo usar o pseudo-elemento do CSS com JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Quero que, ao clicar no pseudo-elemento, o menu abra, tentei diversos códigos mas nenhum funcionou, o último que tentei foi esse :

```
$('#overlay-menu').after().click(function(){
    var menu = $('#overlay-menu'); //Antes eu tentei usar o this, porém, sem sucesso também
    if (menu.className != 'open') {
        menu.className == 'open';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element) no SOen:

> This is not possible; pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM at all so you can't bind any events directly to them, you can only bind to their parent elements.

Ou seja:

> Isso não é possível, pseudo-elementos não fazem parte do DOM, por isso não se pode delegar eventos diretamente nestes, só se pode delegar aos seus pais *(parents)*

Contudo deixo aqui uma melhor alternativa (toggleClass) ao que está a fazer:

```js
$('#overlay-menu').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.open {
  color: red;  
}
#overlay-menu:after {
  content: '++++'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="overlay-menu">HEYA</p>
```

Comment: Então eu teria que criar um span dentro da nav e estiliza-lo como o after, certo ?

Comment: Sim creio que essa seria a solução.. Mas @MuriloGambôa, dê uma olhadela na mecânica de adicionar/remover a class que coloquei. Acho que assim seria melhor para si

Comment: é que como o menu está oculto e há somente um after sendo mostrado pra abrir o menu em overlay, acho que o span seria melhor mesmo, e eu achei muito bom o seu código :3 obrigado pelos esclaecimentos

Comment: De nada @MuriloGambôa, ainda bem que ajudei